# Cannot run anything gem related

Tags: rubygems

Whenever I try to run `compass watch`, I am getting this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                
    4: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'                                                              
    3: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'                                                                             
    2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'                                        
    1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'                           /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
```

I guess my gem installation is messed up because even if I try to do `gem update --system` I get the same issue or any gem related commands.

Is there a way that I can force my gem to update?